# Should the "certificates" and "trusted-root-certificates" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

On SU there are these two tags dealing with certificates:

- [certificate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/certificate)
- [trusted-root-certificates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trusted-root-certificates)

I'm wondering, are they too close to each other to have meaningful difference? I mean, should we just have a general certificates tag and put the "trusted root" questions under that?